# Ionic 3 - sqlite shows error of "can not read property of openDatabase" when run with --prod flag

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I am using [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext) in ionic 3 project. My code is working fine when run without `--prod` flag.

But when i run `ionic cordova run android --prod --relase` it shows "can not read property of openDatabase"

here is my code

```
  export class SqlLiteServiceProvider {
  private options = {name: 'db.db', location: 'default',existingDatabase: 1,createFromLocation:1};
  public win = (<any>window);
  private db : any;

  constructor() {
    try{
      if(this.win.cordova){
        this.db = this.win.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(this.options);

      }else{
        this.db = this.win.openDatabase(this.options.name, '1.0', 'database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
      }
  }catch(ex){
    alert(ex); // always alert error when run with --prod flag
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a production build the `window` object is handled differently as far as I know. When using cordova-plugins which are not included in ionic-native you need to do things a bit different.

Tell typescript that you are sure your plugin handle exists somewhere after the build:

```
declar var SQLitePlugin; // add this at the same level as imports
```

And to use it for example in `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  SQLitePlugin.openDatabase(...);
}
```

But instead of doing this I strongly recommend you using [`@ionic/storage`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) or [`@ionic-native/sqlite`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `ionic cordova run android --prod --relase` with on debug mode. It is for google play store release build. If you need to test on your device you should run below `CLI`.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```